# Application requires JavaScript error when Using Power Query to webscrape

Tags: javascript, powerbi, custom-code, pubchem

Trying to access PubChem via Power BI however I am running into the following issue:

`This application requires Javascript. Please turn on Javascript in order to use this application.`

Just wondering if anyone knows why this occurs and if there is any workarounds to it?

Appears to be somewhat of a local issue to PubChem however, I have successfully accessed pages here before via Power BI/Query.

M Code:

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/311"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "BODY"}}),
    Column1 = #"Extracted Table From Html"[Column1]{0}
in
    Column1
```

This question here appears to also run into this isue:
[Selenium Chrome web driver inconsistently executes JS scripts on webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873563/selenium-chrome-web-driver-inconsistently-executes-js-scripts-on-webpages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is loading JSON from an API in the background so needs the JS to load it. Just access the API directly.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/311/JSON/")),
    Record = Source[Record],
    Section = Record[Section]
in
    Section
```

Comment: Also, don't use Web.BrowserContents. Watch this video here for a good overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVnhUvapQFc

Comment: This is potentially game changing thanks